# Ant Design - Numberinput for € amount

Tags: reactjs, formatting, currency, antd

I use Ant Design and want to create formatted numberinput to let the user provide
an amount with commata.

So the formatted numberinput should display the value as:

- 1,34€
- 18,23€
- 100,24€
- 1400,87€
- 10.983,34€

I want to achieve providing € values with cents.

How is it possible to use the euro currency correctly ? Maybe a regex pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the method provided in the docs?

https://ant.design/components/input-number/#components-input-number-demo-formatter

(I am assuming you already saw it due to your level of reputation... ;-) )

Comment: Generally spoken there is a technical possibility - the AntD formatter. But I do not want to use a self created regex pattern for that. I am looking for a hundred thousands / million times tested, really good regex pattern.

Comment: Well, nothing in your questions mentions regex patterns, so if that is what you are looking for it needs an edit!

Comment: I am also open for other solutions ;)